# different titles for each element after using facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

After setting ncol = 1 in the `facet_wrap()` function, I'm trying to use `ggtitle()` function inside the `facet_wrap()` function to set a different title for each graph created (there are only two of them).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ var, ncol = 1) +
  ggtitle(function(x) paste("Title for", df$title[df$var == x]))
```

I'm trying to use the value of the "title" column of the dataframe, where the value of the "var" column matches the value of the current plot's var.

But I get this error:

```
Error in as.character(x$label) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

How can I set different titles for each graph in ggplot2 using the facet_wrap() function with ncol=1?

Thanks, Ido

Comment: I believe the `title` attribute (whether defined in `ggtitle` or `labs(title = `) belongs to the whole plot and not separate to each facet. Do you want to alter the facet headers? If you want separate titles you probably need separate plots, which can be combined and aligned with `patchwork`.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Usually you have a tittle for the plot and strip labels for each facet. If you want separate plots with different titles then you should make those plots separately and use something like `patchwork` or `cowplot` to concatenate them. A [reproducible example](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that might give you what you want. My comment above still stands, but this may be more what you are looking for.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(strip_title = paste(cyl, "Cylinders"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~strip_title, ncol = 1)
```

[image]